# Estimating the number of sides of a die

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, dice

A friend of mine inspired this question:

Given a fair die, can one accurately estimate (within some margin) the size of the die given enough rolls? For example: If I roll a die 1000 times and all the numbers fall on and between 1 and 5, I estimate the size of the die is 5.

My question is: is this an accurate estimate? Will we always be able to predict the size of the die within some margin of error?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that you know that it starts with a 1 and goes up (without skipping any numbers)?

Comment: Do you know how many sides the die has?

Comment: To clarify: We're assuming the die starts at 1 and goes up to some number n. The only information we are given is the results of k rolls.

The question then becomes:
How large does k have to be in order to get a good enough estimate?

Comment: I'm still unclear as to whether you know how many sides the die has. Does "goes up to some number $n$" mean it has n sides numbered $1$ to $n$, or that it has some known number of sides with a maximum value of $n$ on one (or more) of the sides?

Comment: Like the post says: the only information you are given is the result of k rolls. This does NOT include the size of the die.

Comment: For a very large number like $n = 1000$ rolls of a fair die with 'sides' numbered from 1 through K, the best estimate of K would be the maximum number seen in the 1000 rolls. For smaller numbers of rolls you need to take into account that the max can be smaller than K, but never larger. So the max is biased towards being a little small.  I'm not sure if you're working at a level where it is fair to ask you how to 'unbias' the die. Example: in 1000 simulated rolls of a ten sided die (K = 10), I got a max of 10. But the first time I tried simulating only $n = 20$ rolls, I got a max of only 9.

Comment: Simulation: In 100,000 20-roll experiments with a 10-sided die, I got max = 10 about 88% of the time, max = 9 about 11% of the time and occasional smaller numbers. Maybe you can see how to use combinatorics to find probabilities for such occurrences, and thus see what your 'margin of error' might be.

Comment: This is like the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) except that in that problem, repetition is not allowed, and here it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bruce has said in the comments, the most obvious choice for the estimator of the number of sides is the maximum of all the $k$ rolls seen.  Let's take that and see what we can learn about it.

Let $x_i$ be the result of the $i$th roll.  Then our estimator is
$$
\hat{N} \equiv \max_i \; x_i.
$$
So the way that the estimator would fail, would be if the largest value of the die doesn't come up in the $k$ rolls.  Because the die is assumed to be fair the probability distribution for each value is equal:
$$
P(x_i = n) = \frac{1}{N}, \qquad \forall \quad i, \text{and for any } n. 
$$
The probability that $N$ doesn't get rolled would be
$$
P(x_i \ne N) = 1 - P(x_i = N) = 1 - \frac{1}{N}.
$$
Over the full course of $k$ rolls, we can calculate the probability of never rolling the largest value $(N)$ as
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k (x_i \ne N)\right) = \prod_{i=1}^k P(x_i \ne N)
= \left( 1- \frac{1}{N}\right)^k = \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^k.
$$
Now say that we want to compare this with some margin of error $\epsilon$. ( For example, an $\epsilon= 0.01$ would represent a 1% possibility that the largest number doesn't show up in our $k$ rolls.)
$$
\begin{split}
\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^k &\le \epsilon \\
k\;\underbrace{\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{N}\right)}_{<\,0} &\le \log(\epsilon) \\
k &\ge \frac{\log{\epsilon}}{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)}
\end{split}
$$
So, given a margin $\epsilon$ set to any arbitrary value (well, it must be positive and less than 1), and the number of sides of the die, we can tell how many rolls $(k)$ we need to achieve that confidence. A couple of tables below show some values of $k$ given an $N$.
$$
\epsilon = 0.01
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l|cccccccccc}
N &   2  &   4    & 6&     8&    10    &12    &20    &26    &40    &100\\
\hline
k &   7 &   17    &26    &35    &44    &53    &90   &118   &182   &459
\end{array}
$$
$$
\epsilon = 0.001
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l|cccccccccc}
N &     2   &  4     &6     &8    &10    &12    &20    &26    &40   &100 \\
\hline
k&     10    &25    &38    &52    &66    &80   &135   &177   &273   &688
\end{array}
$$
Alternatively, we can plug in the number of rolls and see how large a die we can identify with a set margin for error.
This can be found by backing out what $N$ can be identified within a margin $\epsilon$ with a given $k$.  Working it backwards from above, you get something that looks like
$$
N \le \frac{1}{1 - e^{\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{k}}},
$$
which says that for $k =1000$, you'd be able to identify a 216-sided die with a 99% probability, and an 87-sided die with a 99.999% probability.